# Multiple conditions in conditional formatting, highlighting if both conditions are met

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been trying to figure out how to make it so that based on a date on "December 2022" the conditional formatting will look at "Data" to see if the date exists in B. That part I have nailed down no problem, where I can't make this work is I also want to have in the same formula a secondary check that matches the header for the given date to the "Data" page where the exact same data point gets populated. On "December 2022" I've already set up my conditional formatting to black out  when something shouldn't be posted. It's figuring out how to pull the data from the checkbox on "Social Posts" which automatically copy the data over to "Data" that I'm at a complete loss for.

Looking around in various places I've tried a few that seemed like they may work, but adding in the second condition breaks it instantly.

```
=ArrayFormula(countif(indirect("Data!$B$2:$B"),$A2:$A))>0
=match(N1,indirect("Data!A1:A"),0)
=if(A14,indirect("Data!B1:B"),0)

=indirect("Data!B1:B"),A36=indirect("Data!A1:A")).

=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A14, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 FILTER(INDIRECT("Data!C:C"), INDIRECT("Data!A:A")=TRUE))))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15dKvI9w1lyuN3B4BjFVyFiS2l9zgK6UJbWwjM48qpVU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've solicited access

Comment: I've given access!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you now, for what I understand you need. Please clarify if it doesn't or provide an example of a potential match.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT ("Data!B:B"),MATCH(D$1, INDIRECT ("Data!A:A") ,0))=$A2
```

[image]

Comment: I set thé conditions in a copy of December

Comment: The dark area isn't what I'm trying to figure out. Though that is a much cleaner way of doing that! I'm trying to find a way to have the date on December and Data match up while also looking at the header on December and the A column on Data in the same condition. So if it were to say what it has there, it highlights the appropriate box on the December stat sheet. Etc... For any other day and option that appears.

Comment: Check if the new update works for you

Comment: It works like I envisioned it! There are just some that will not work with the formula for whatever reason, so I'm going to play around with changing the naming scheme to see if that works. One example is G10 will not highlight with the conditional formatting if the date and task is on the Data sheet.

Comment: It also seems to dislike multiple entries of the same thing if the date is different. I may have to approach this a different way potentially?

Comment: The first thing is because of the order of your conditional formatting options. You have to set-up the green up. You should consider unifying all in just three rules as I suggested or you're going to go crazy ordering and updating the formulas for each small change in each column

Comment: About the second thing, are you going to have more than one entry per item?